# Optional type use in scala play framework in form

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to use form input without any validation. (value is optional) so i tried to use optional type in form but its pop up some error. Simply I need to do is create a form with 4 input fields and 3 of them need to validate as text values only  and another field with optionally (its value can be empty or not) and its not validate in the form submission

> Read from stdout:
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\Project_VendorM6\app\models\ProductSearch.scala:6:
>   not found: type optional
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\Project_VendorM6\app\models\ProductSearch.scala:6:
>   not found: type optional Read from stdout: case class
>   ProductSearch(proname:
>   String,brandid:String,typeid:String,supplierid:optional[String])
>       case class ProductSearch(proname: String,brandid:String,typeid:String,supplierid:optional[String]) Read
>   from stdout: ^

here is my form validation in controller

```
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.{mapping, nonEmptyText,bigDecimal,text,number,optional}
 private val productSearchForm: Form[ProductSearch] = Form(
            mapping(
                "proname" -> text,
                "probrand" -> text,
                "protype" -> text,
                "prosup" -> optional(text) 

            )(ProductSearch.apply)(ProductSearch.unapply)
        )
```

And here is my Model

```
package models
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

    case class ProductSearch(proname: String,brandid:String,typeid:String,supplierid:optional[String])


        object ProductSearch {


        }
```

I tried it without the optional key word in model as follows

```
case class ProductSearch(proname: String,brandid:String,typeid:String,supplierid:String)
```

but then its pop-up two compile errors

> Read from stdout:
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\Project_VendorM6\app\controllers\Products.scala:39:
>   type mismatch; Read from stdout: found   : (String, String, String,
>   String) => models.ProductSearch Read from stdout: required: (String,
>   String, String, Option[String]) => ?

and

> Read from stdout:
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\Project_VendorM6\app\controllers\Products.scala:39:
>   missing arguments for method unapply in object ProductSearch; Read
>   from stdout: follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a
>   partially applied function
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\Project_VendorM6\app\controllers\Products.scala:39:
>   missing arguments for method unapply in object ProductSearch; follow
>   this method with`_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied
>   function Read from stdout:
>   )(ProductSearch.apply)(ProductSearch.unapply)
>               )(ProductSearch.apply)(ProductSearch.unapply)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there. Your definition of the model object should use a Scala `Option`:

```
case class ProductSearch(proname:String,
                         brandid:String,
                         typeid:String,
                         supplierid:Option[String])
```